# Append something to the border of an object

Tags: jquery, html

Can I use the `border` of an HTML element and `append()` it to the border itself, so that it doesn't move when you scroll (I'm using the  `position: fixed` method because I do not like the way it looks)?

Comment: border is not a DOM element, but a style, so no, you cannot. If you post a fiddle or show some code we might be able to help you out :P

Comment: Oh ok I got you! Gimme one sec please